# Show values in another value in sql

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want show value 1 by 'this i number one' in result of query sql. I'm looking for a statement like ALIAS but using for values, not column. 
Ex: 
id|
0|
1|
1|
When excute query results sholud be:
id|
this is number zero|
this is number one|
this is number one|

Thanks!

Comment: you want to show value 1000 by 1.000.000 in result of query sql?.. What is it?

Comment: It's like ALIAS statement, when query excute, user get 1.000, not 1000. :D

Comment: Sorry, i don't know English :D

Comment: no problem with English - I'm not native speaker either. Please update the question. I can see how 1000 trasoforms to 1.000, but not to 1.000.000 and that what you currently have in a question

Comment: for `psql` it would be `\pset numericlocale on`, for other client read on `lc_numeric` and `to_char` I suppose

Comment: So, you want to [**format** your numbers](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-formatting.html#FUNCTIONS-FORMATTING-EXAMPLES-TABLE)?

Comment: I'm sorry, that not about number. Ex: i have table id that have 2 value 0,1. Can i using SELECT id FROM table WITH 0 AS zero AND 1 AS one;

Comment: `with t(id) as (values(0),(1),(1)) select * from t join (values(0,'this is number zero'),(1,'this is number one'),(2,'this is number two')) as decode(id,v) on (t.id = decode.id);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Ex: i have table id that have 2 value 0,1. Can i using SELECT id FROM table WITH 0 AS zero AND 1 AS one;
>
> I hope my result should be: id|zero|zero|one|...

If I correct understood, you need something like this:

```
with t(id) as (
    select 0
    union all
    select 1
    -- another values
)
select id as original_value,
CASE 
    WHEN id = 0 THEN 'zero' 
    WHEN id = 1 THEN 'one' 
    -- another values
END as changed_value   
from t
```

Comment: Thanks! That's all i need :D